# Add True Value to Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
CASE 
    WHEN VPN_Access__c = True THEN 'Need to Setup' + VPN_Access__c 
    ELSE '' 
END AS VPNAccessDesc`
```

I'm trying to create a Case statement but I keep getting an error stating invalid column name 'True'.  It's a checkbox field and I want it to say "Need to Setup" if the table equals True.

`VPN_Access__c` is a `bit` datatype if that makes a difference

Comment: What type is the field 'VPN_Access__c'?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sql Server doesn't have `boolean` values, so you'll need to do:

```
CASE WHEN VPN_Access__c = 1 THEN 'Need to Setup' 
ELSE '' END AS VPNAccessDesc
```

Actually - you can remove `+ VPN_Access__c` as it makes more sense to say `Need to Setup` rather than `Need to Setup1`

Comment: MySQL does: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/boolean-values.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/boolean-values.html)

Comment: mysql does, though you concatenate strings with CONCAT(), not +

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which database you're using, but in mysql5, BIT isn't the same as BOOLEAN, it's a bit field, you can't reliably compare it to true/false